# Can't connect to host using OpenSSL in C++

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

When I try to connect to some hosts(not all) through HTTPS using OpenSSL in C++ I gets OpenSSL error `error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure`. I'm using `TLS_client_method` SSL method. But if I use openssl test executable, it's ok - `openssl s_client -connect host:443 -tls1_2`.
My connect code here:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = TLS_client_method();
inet->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
inet->ssl = SSL_new(inet->ssl_ctx);
SSL_set_fd(inet->ssl, s);
int err = SSL_connect(inet->ssl);
```

Why? Maybe I need some *.pem/*.pm files? I don't know, but I saw it somewhere.

Comment: To which hosts do you fail connecting to? If it is a handshake failure maybe the problem is on the host?

Comment: @darclander, I think no, I tried to connect to `hostiman.ru`, I can connect to this website using simple web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not use the SNI extension when connecting to the server, i.e. does not include the hostname of the server into the TLS handshake. Multi-domain sites usually require SNI and might fail or return some unrelated certificate when SNI is not provided. This is also true for CDN like Cloudflare where different domains are accessible by the same IP address but should result in different certificates.

> ... I tried to connect to hostiman.ru

This is for example the case with hostiman.ru. With SNI (as set by newer `s_client` versions by default):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect hostiman.ru:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000005)
...
depth=0 C = US, ST = CA, L = San Francisco, O = "Cloudflare, Inc.", CN = sni.cloudflaressl.com
...
   Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

Without SNI it instead looks like this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect hostiman.ru:443 -tls1_2 -noservername
CONNECTED(00000005)
140420123775424:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1528:SSL alert number 40
...
    Cipher    : 0000
```

To setup SNI in the client use [SSL_set_tlsext_host_name](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get_servername_type.html), i.e.

```
inet->ssl = SSL_new(inet->ssl_ctx);
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(inet->ssl, servername)
```